# How to I get billing address information from Braintree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

I am using Braintree and their transaction redirect service in order to process transactions. According to Braintree's documentation, you should be able to collect billing information. I have the form set up to do so, but for some reason the billing information is not present in the response, or in the transaction if I pull it later using `Braintree::Transaction.find`. Here is the form code:

```
    <%= form_tag(Braintree::TransparentRedirect.url, method: "post", id: 'braintree-transaction-form') do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :tr_data, @tr_data  %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :amount, @dress.price %>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Credit Card Information</legend>

        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <%= label_tag "transaction[credit_card][number]", "Credit card number" %>
          <%= text_field_tag "transaction[credit_card][number]", nil, { 'data-encrypted-name' => 'transaction[credit_card][number]' }  %>
        </div>

        <div class="large-8 columns">
          <%= label_tag 'transaction[credit_card][cardholder_name]', "Cardholder Name" %>
          <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[credit_card][cardholder_name]' %>
        </div>
        <div class="large-2 columns">
          <%= label_tag 'transaction[credit_card][expiration_month]', "Expiration Date" %>
          <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[credit_card][expiration_month]', nil, { 'max-length' => 2, 'data-encrypted-name' => 'transaction[credit_card][expiration_month]', 'placeholder' => 'MM' } %>
        </div>
        <div class="large-2 columns">
          <label>&nbsp;</label>
          <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[credit_card][expiration_year]', nil,  { 'max-length' => 4, 'data-encrypted-name' => 'transaction[credit_card][expiration_year]', 'placeholder' => 'YYYY' } %>
        </div>

        <div class="large-3 columns end">
          <%= label_tag 'transaction[credit_card][cvv]', "CVV" %>
          <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[credit_card][cvv]', nil, { 'max-length' => 4, 'data-encrypted-name' => 'transaction[credit_card][cvv]' } %>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Shipping Information</legend>

      <div class='large-6 columns'>
        <%= label_tag 'transaction[shipping][first_name]',  "First Name" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[shipping][first_name]' %>
      </div>

      <div class='large-6 columns'>
        <%= label_tag 'transaction[shipping][last_name]', "Last Name" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[shipping][last_name]' %>
      </div>

      <div class='large-12 columns'>
        <%= label_tag 'transaction[shipping][street_address]', "Address Line 1" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[shipping][street_address]' %>
      </div>

      <div class='large-12 columns'>
        <%= label_tag 'transaction[shipping][extended_address]', "Address Line 2" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[shipping][extended_address]' %>
      </div>

      <div class='large-4 columns'>
        <%= label_tag 'transaction[shipping][locality]', "City" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[shipping][locality]' %>
      </div>

      <div class='large-4 columns'>
        <%= label_tag 'transaction[shipping][region]', "State" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[shipping][region]' %>
      </div>

      <div class='large-4 columns'>
        <%= label_tag 'transaction[shipping][postal_code]', "Zip Code" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[shipping][postal_code]' %>
      </div>

</fieldset>

<%= submit_tag "Get The Dress!", { 'class' => 'large button expand' } %>

  <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you include a link to the portion of the documentation on which you're basing your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more help, feel free to [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Your form isn't gathering billing address info, just shipping address info. If you change `shipping` to `billing` or add another section:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>billing Information</legend>

  <div class='large-6 columns'>
    <%= label_tag 'transaction[billing][first_name]',  "First Name" %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[billing][first_name]' %>
  </div>

  <div class='large-6 columns'>
    <%= label_tag 'transaction[billing][last_name]', "Last Name" %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[billing][last_name]' %>
  </div>

  <div class='large-12 columns'>
    <%= label_tag 'transaction[billing][street_address]', "Address Line 1" %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[billing][street_address]' %>
  </div>

  <div class='large-12 columns'>
    <%= label_tag 'transaction[billing][extended_address]', "Address Line 2" %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[billing][extended_address]' %>
  </div>

  <div class='large-4 columns'>
    <%= label_tag 'transaction[billing][locality]', "City" %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[billing][locality]' %>
  </div>

  <div class='large-4 columns'>
    <%= label_tag 'transaction[billing][region]', "State" %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[billing][region]' %>
  </div>

  <div class='large-4 columns'>
    <%= label_tag 'transaction[billing][postal_code]', "Zip Code" %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'transaction[billing][postal_code]' %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

the resulting transaction will have a [`transaction.billing_details` attribute](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/transactions/details#id132):

> **transaction.billing_details**
>
> The billing address details used to process this transaction. If billing address was stored in the Vault, then the billing_address_details is a snapshot of the address in the Vault at the time the transaction was created. So if the address in the Vault is updated after the transaction is created, transaction.billing_address_details.postal_code will return the previous postal code that was used to process the transaction, while transaction.vault_billing_address.postal_code will return the current postal code for the address in the Vault.
>
> The address details are similar to those found on the address details page.

```
transaction.billing_details.company
transaction.billing_details.country_code_alpha2
transaction.billing_details.country_code_alpha3
transaction.billing_details.country_code_numeric
transaction.billing_details.country_name
transaction.billing_details.extended_address
transaction.billing_details.first_name
transaction.billing_details.last_name
transaction.billing_details.locality
transaction.billing_details.postal_code
transaction.billing_details.region
transaction.billing_details.street_address
```

Comment: are you around ,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: @JotDhaliwal If you're trying to get help about Braintree, [visit our support site](https://support.braintreepayments.com/)

Comment: It doesnt provide help in the vb.net sir

Comment: @JotDhaliwal If you email our support team, they'll help you.